# Search and test connection to AWS RDS using Windows Power Shell

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, networking, tfs, rds

I am trying to install and configure TFS Server on Windows 2012 AWS EC2 instance. I will like to configure an RDS SQL Server as backend but I am facing some issues with the connection so I am testing the ports and the connection using this command:

```
Test-NetConnection -Port 1433 -ComputerName tfsserver.sqlserver.region.rds.amazonaws.com -InformationLevel Detailed
```

And the command result is:

```
ComputerName             : tfsserver.sqlserver.region.rds.amazonaws.com
RemoteAddress            : sql_server_address
RemotePort               : 1433
AllNameResolutionResults : sql_server_address
MatchingIPsecRules       : 
NetworkIsolationContext  : Internet
InterfaceAlias           : Ethernet
SourceAddress            : tfs_server_address
NetRoute (NextHop)       : gateway_hop_address
PingSucceeded            : False
PingReplyDetails (RTT)   : 0 ms
TcpTestSucceeded         : False
```

**Note: I changed originals IP address and RDS endpoint name**

My issue here is:

The ping command is not allowed in my security group so how do I know if the connection is open because:

```
TcpTestSucceeded         : False
```

Is that result related with the ping command or is the **1433** port closed? I will like to know if the connection is open.

Comment: I added other centos instances to the RDS security group and the port is open. Same rule but different instance. From centos I tested using telnet. I  do not know where is the issue. I also turned off the windows firewall.

Answer (score 2):

That is a result of the tcp port not being accessible. Either as it's not open, its not allowed somewhere along the path (local firewall, route or RDS security group)

If you specify the -Port parameter then it's a TCP test not an ICMP echo (ping) https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn372891.aspx